# Accessing Room data in Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-room, android-viewmodel

In my android app,
I have implemented Room architecture with repository and view model..

My app also use Broadcast receiver.

I want to access data of Room in my broadcast receiver..but view model can't be accessed as for that I need application context which I don't have in broadcast receiver..

So suggest a way how to access data from Room database.

Thankyou in advance..

Comment: Why would you want to access the view model? Use your broadcast receiver `onReceive`'s application context to instantiate the database.

Comment: But it returns in the form of livedata and so how to get particular data from this livedata list???